# Jetty and Java EE 8

Tags: jakarta-ee, jetty, jetty-9

Two weeks ago Java EE 8 was released. And new Tomcat 9 was announced to support it.
Are there any plans for Jetty to support Java EE8? I couldn't find any information about that in the documentation or on Jetty site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it will be Jetty 10 and we'll be pushing out a beta release for that fairly soon.

To be clear though Jetty will likely never support a fully JavaEE specification, our focus remains strictly oriented towards the Servlet api and generally towards technologies and protocols that integrate well like websockets, http2, while maintaining our high volume/low latency goals.  While the new specifications are released there is some churn related to where they are moving to (the Eclipse Foundation) which is where we develop Jetty so we are pausing a little bit to see how this plays out before we push fully towards Jetty 10 final.

[Update] Current thinking has been that we would push out Jetty 10 with JakartaEE specification references. This migration process is taking longer than we had originally anticipated but we continue to hold on to that plan for the time being.  If you would like to provide feedback on that process feel free to post to the dev mailing list.

Comment: To be clear, like Jetty, Tomcat is (a) aimed at Servlet/JSP work but not a full Java EE implementation and (b) is not yet shipping a version supporting full Servlet 4.0 of the Java EE 8 spec. The Tomcat 9 mentioned in the Question is in beta and not yet recommended for production, while the recommended Tomcat 8.5 supports the Servlet spec version 3.x, just like the current version of Jetty.

Comment: Thank you, Jesse. Do you have any estimations on the Jetty 10 release date?

Comment: We figure we'll have a BETA out before the end of the year.  It seems new servlet api versions generate very little immediate interest so it hasn't been a huge priority for us.  The SNAPSHOT builds of our master branch are basically servlet 4 right if you want to take a look.  I'll note that we'll likely be moving the name of the master branch over to jetty-10.0.x relatively soon so don't be shocked if you go look for master and don't find it there. :)